# ImportError: No module named redis - Docker

Tags: python, docker, redis

I could not get rid of this error. I already installed redis using `sudo pip install redis` and `sudo easy_install redis` . I test it out redis on terminal with "python" and "python3" commands and it's working as expected but i cannot run on docker application, when i start container i get the following error:

```
import redis   
application_1       | ImportError: No module named redis
```

Here is python file that i got the error from:

```
import redis
from application_1 import logger
redis_client = redis.StrictRedis()
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:2-alpine
ENV INSTALL_PATH /application_1
RUN mkdir -p $INSTALL_PATH

WORKDIR $INSTALL_PATH

# update needed for wget
# update tar .. --strip-componenets not available in current version
# install permanent deps
RUN apk --update add --no-cache ca-certificates wget tar xz postgresql-dev
RUN update-ca-certificates

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt

# install deps
RUN apk update
RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual build-dependencies gcc python-dev libevent- 
dev linux-headers musl-dev \
&& pip install -r requirements.txt \
&& apk del build-dependencies

# install ffmpeg
COPY scripts/set_ffmpeg.sh scripts/set_ffmpeg.sh
RUN ash scripts/set_ffmpeg.sh

# copy remaining files
COPY . .

CMD python app.py
```

Any idea on how to fix this issue ?

Comment: post your dockerfile and mention how you have "installed redis with every possible methods"

Comment: You install redis in host, but run the code in container?

Comment: @atline I mean when i run the code on docker container i got the error and yes i installed redis in host.

Comment: So, you need to install redis in container, container & host do not share environment.

Comment: `RUN pip install redis` to your dockerfile.

Comment: update your `requirements.txt` to include redis